# How to condition appearance of div in Knockout JS based on value from $root?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to show/hide a div in my code based on a certain value. Using Knockout JS context debugger I found the property I need to compare in $root context. The property path I get from developer console is :
`$root_toJS.items.mainItems[0].itemDescription.productId`

I tried several methods, basically different variations of the 'ko if' in the following code, but nothing works:

```
<!-- ko if: $root.items.mainItems[0].itemDescription.productId != 1 -->
    <div class="action-row">
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: execute" class="btn-primary fiori3-btn-primary">

            <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Is there any way I can acces the value at the specified path in a 'ko if' condition?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

when you're referring to your `name` variable I'm assuming it's in the context of your itemDescription, so you have to make sure you're using the exact location of it also.

In my 2nd example I'm using a `foreach` loop to go over all the mainItems. Pay attention to the `as: mainItem` alias where I don't need to enter the entire thing anymore, you could also use `$data` but that only complicates it imo.

```js
class ViewModel {
  constructor() {
    this.items = {
      mainItems: [{
        itemDescription: {
          productId: 1,
          name: 'item one',
        }
      }, {
        itemDescription: {
          productId: 2,
          name: 'item two',
        }
      }]
    };
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<h5>this breaks any generic approach but is as your example:</h5>
<!-- ko if: $root.items.mainItems[0].itemDescription.productId !== 1 -->
<div>
  <span data-bind="text: $root.items.mainItems[0].itemDescription.name"></span>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: $root.items.mainItems[1].itemDescription.productId !== 1 -->
<div>
  <span data-bind="text: $root.items.mainItems[1].itemDescription.name"></span>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->

<h5>this embraces it what is probably more what you'd want:</h5>
<!-- ko foreach: { data: $root.items.mainItems, as: 'mainItems' } -->
<!-- ko if: mainItems.itemDescription.productId !== 1 -->
<div>
  <span data-bind="text: mainItems.itemDescription.name"></span>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```